# Is there any command in turtle which stops turtle from further drawing?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a tkinter based program which used turtle graphics to draw graphs. I have a button which draws a square in the screen. But when I press that button while turtle is drawing something else, the turtle start to draw square and after finishing it again continue its previous task. I don't want it to continue it previous function. I want to directly stop it wherever it is and just do its new job.
This is the sample code but this is not actually what I need it for. I have tried to simplify the problem.
    import tkinter as tk
    from turtle import RawTurtle

```
def square():
    t.up()
    t.home()
    t.down()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.rt(90)

def drawseries():
    l = 2
    for i in range(100):
        t.fd(l)
        t.lt(90)
        l += 2

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root,command = square, text = 'Draw Square')
button.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

t = RawTurtle(canvas)
drawseries()
```

Comment: `turtle.penup()` maybe?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: turtle.penup() doesn't help. It just dont shows it drawing but continue to do whatever it is doing. I have added code too now.

Comment: `turtle.done()` or `turtle.mainloop()` maybe? (they're supposed to do the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

You are always calling the `drawseries()` command at the end of the file. When the for loop is done, it calls `drawseries()` again.